# How we can pass data into vuex action

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuex-modules

I'm not very comfortable with action in vuex.

I wan't to call in my Login component an vuex action who make api call with axios.

But the data who is transferred since my component is not receive in the action..

I don't know how to make this work..

```
this.$store.dispatch('REGISTER', {
          username: this.username,
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        })
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
          this.$router.push('/login')
        })
        .catch (() => {
          this.error = true;
        })
```

and in my vuex module :

```
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  state: {},
  mutations: {},
  getters: {},
  actions: {
    REGISTER: ({ username, email, password }) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios
          .post(process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL + "auth/register", {
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password
          })
          .then(({ data, status }) => {
            if (status === 201) {
              localStorage.setItem('access_token', data.data.token);
              resolve(true);
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            reject(error);
          });
      });
    },
  }
};
```

Thank's

Answer (score 2):

You're passing an object to the vuex action. Try to modify your action method thus:

```
REGISTER: ({ commit }, data) => {
let {username, email, password} = data
```

EDIT:
Specifically, the first argument any vuex action receives is a context object containing commit, state, getters, and dispatch. The second argument is any object that you pass along to it through your call to dispatch. – [maiorano84](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1347308/maiorano84)

Comment: Specifically, the first argument any vuex action receives is a context object containing `commit`, `state`, `getters`, and `dispatch`. The second argument is any object that you pass along to it through your call to `dispatch`.